# How to calculate gradient from function in python - tuple IndexError?

Tags: python, math, tuples, gradient

I'm looking to find the gradient, at point x, for the following function:

```
f(x) = w1 * x1^2 + w2 * x2
```

My code so far:

```
def gradient(w1, w2, x):
   gradient = w1 * (x[0]**2) + w2 * (x[1]**2)
   return gradient
```

However, this doesn't work for the following e.g

```
w1 = 5; w2 = 3; x = (1,)
```

I'm receiving this error:
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Does this mean one of my indices is wrong? I thought a tuple only has two index 0 & 1. Apologies - appreciate this may be a v basic question.

Comment: length of x is 1, x[0] = 1, x[1] what is that?????????? Tuple can be of any length

Answer (score 0):

It works for you, you just passed only one value to the tuple, and you need two. If you wanted to pass zero in this way, then this is incorrect. `(1,)` - > `(1, 0)`

```
def gradient(w1, w2, x):
   gradient = w1 * (x[0]**2) + w2 * (x[1]**2)
   return gradient

w1 = 5
w2 = 3
x = (1,0)
print(gradient(w1,w2,x))
```

Output:

```
5
```